# I am getting an issue in opportunity for stage where I put trigger

Tags: trigger, opportunity, administration

I got this message.

**" You encountered some errors when trying to save this record
There's a problem saving this record. You might not have permission to edit it, or it might have been deleted or archived. Contact your administrator for help ".**

I put trigger on 'Closed Won' but got error message. Than change trigger on previous stage to test. I Got same error for that stage too and 'Closed Won' start working fine. I am stuck in this. I have 'System Administrator' profile.
My trigger is working quit fine in my trailhead org. here, i am initiating POST callout upon trigger response. I am using Enterprise Edition.

Any input will be highly appreciated.

```
trigger won_opportunity on Opportunity (after update) {

    List<Opportunity> opp = new List<Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
    {
        if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
            //Negotiation
            System.debug('id is: ' + opp.Id);
            String oppID = opp.Id;

            opp = [SELECT Name, Id,City__c, BIC_SWIFT_code__c, Building__c FROM Opportunity]; //Limit 1
            String json_opp = JSON.serialize(opp);
            Opportunity_Post.callout(json_opp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the body of your question. Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: @DavidReed code also added . check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the compiler ought to complain about this code, although it does not. You're doing a couple of things here that change the behavior of your code in ways you might not expect.

```
List<Opportunity> opp = new List<Opportunity>();
for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
```

Here, you've shadowed a declaration of a `List<Opportunity>` with a declaration of an `Opportunity`. You should probably remove the list declaration since, as we'll see below, you don't need it.

```
{
    if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
        //Negotiation
        System.debug('id is: ' + opp.Id);
        String oppID = opp.Id;
```

You're not using this variable, so you can safely remove it.

```
        opp = [SELECT Name, Id,City__c, BIC_SWIFT_code__c, Building__c FROM Opportunity]; //Limit 1
```

This is the big problem, and I suspect it's what leads to the error you're pointing to once `Opportunity_Post.callout()` is called. Here, you're just querying every Opportunity in your database, and assigning the result to a single `Opportunity` variable. If you have multiple records present in your database, that'll get you a [`QueryException`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm).

Since you're in `after update` context and not using any cross-relationship fields, all of this data will already be present on the records in `Trigger.new`. In other words, you don't need to query again, unless you're trying to mutate these records (in `after update`, the trigger sObjects are read-only). You can serialize either one or all of the trigger's sObjects and pass them to your method directly.

```
        String json_opp = JSON.serialize(opp);
        Opportunity_Post.callout(json_opp);
```

I assume that `callout()` is a future method or a synchronous method that itself calls a future methd. Be aware that the transaction limit for future method calls is 50. If your trigger is called with more than 50 records in a transaction, you will get a `LimitException` and the whole transaction will be rolled back. Think carefully about your integration architecture here, because it has very real consequences for the future of your org.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed. It helps me a lot and my problem is solved now.